# Django form - save option not in dropdown list

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I have an interdependant drop down in a Django form. I leave the second drop down empty because i use jQuery to fill the options.

**forms.py**

```
self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.none()
```

Flow:

1. In the first dropdown i select product_type
2. jQuery fills the second drop down with product options
3. I select a product from the second drop down
4. Save

When i save the form i get an error because the options selected are not available in the dropdown when the form initially loads.

How can i disable the form validation on this drop down so it lets me save options that where not available on form load?

On request, forms.py

```
class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderLineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.helper.error_text_inline = False
        self.fields['product'].queryset = self.fields['product'].queryset.filter(product_type_id=self.instance.product_type_id)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(removed - not relevant)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: The options for the second dropdown are in the js? Any ajax involved? It is a bit unclear to me what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I get the product options based on the selected product_type (on change), this is because i have 1000+ options - this works fine. If i would remove self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.none() the form saves fine.

Comment: Your question is still not clear: `products` is the first or the second? How is the second populated?

Comment: First drop down is product type, second drop down is products. When i select a product_type the products drop down gets populated through JSON.

Comment: quick fix would be to make edits in forms.py, you can set the fields requirement to false which would then make the validation not check the field eg `field_foo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=sorted(CHOICES),required=False)`

Comment: I use ModelChoiceFiled - added required false, same error -         product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.filter(product_type_id=self.instance.product_type_id), required=False)
        self.fields['product'] = product

Comment: Please post the complete code in forms.py

Comment: Could you also post the FormHelper Code?

Comment: The form helper is standard from crispy forms --- from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

Comment: in the class init a field like `field_name_to_access = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=sorted(CHOICES),required=False)` not 
as `field_name_to_access =
 forms.ModelChoiceField(choices=sorted(CHOICES),required=False)`

Here CHOICES is a list which contains all the options in the field

should be a member of `OrderLineForm` class
eg.

`class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):CHOICES=list()#put something in CHOICES field_name_access_from_page= forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=sorted(CHOICES),required=False)`